# Regular Expression (Notepad++) find all in CSV like log file where a particular column is NOT 0 or 00

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to use the Notepad++ RegEx feature to search through a few thousand files to match a particular pattern. The files contain logged data with the lines of interest starting with "LOG:" followed by comma separated data. Of these lines I am interested in finding those where a certain column does not equal "0" or "00".

Example data set. I am interested in the 5th column as shown in **bold**:

LOG:69369,1,30,40,**80**,06,1
LOG:69369,1,30,40,**C0**,06,1
POS:69453,69576034,-19244227,1,0
LOG:69405,2,30,40,**00**,06,2
POS:69333,69576024,-19244235,1,0
LOG:69405,2,30,40,**C0**,06,2

To start with I have an expression that does the opposite, that is is finds only those lines where column 5 equals "0" or "00":

```
^(LOG:).*,.*,.*,.*,((0)|(00)),.*$
```

How do I change this to find all the "LOG:" lines where column 5 IS NOT "0" or "00" (In this example I want to match the 1st, 2nd and last lines)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead based regex.

```
^(LOG:)[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,(?!00?(?:,|$))([^,]*)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cB3eE4/1)

Answer (score 0):

> where a **certain** column does not equal "0" or "00"

You can use the following generic regex (if you want to check for `nth` column replace `4` with `n-1`):

```
^(?:LOG:)(?:[^,]*,){4}(?!00?\b)([^,]*).*$
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kW8qS1/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
^LOG:(?:[^,]*,){4}\K(?!0+,)([^,]*)
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cB3eE4/2